# Alocação dinâmica e uso de ponteiros em C

Tags: c

Estou com muitas duvidas em relação a alocação dinâmica e uso de ponteiros em C. Preciso desenvolver alguns exercícios, mas eles estão emperrados porque estou com alguma dificuldade em avançar com o uso de ponteiros e alocação dinâmica. O seguinte esse exercício pede o seguinte:

> Faça um programa que leia um vetor de números reais de tamanho escolhido pelo usuário e descubra qual é o maior e menor valor existente no vetor, junto de seu índice.

Construí da maneira abaixo. Alguém poderia apontar o erro, por favor?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

float *alocaVetor(int n)
{
  float *v;
  v = (float *)malloc(n * sizeof(float));
  return v;
}

void leVetor(float *v, int n)
{
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
  {
    printf("Elemento %d: \n", i);
    scanf("%f", &v[i]);
  }
}

float *comparaVetor(float *v, int n)
{
  float maior = v[0];
  float menor = v[0];

  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
  {
    if (v[i] > maior)
      maior = v[i];
    if (v[i] < menor)
      menor = v[i];
  }
  printf("%f", &maior);
  printf("%f", &menor);

  return v;
}

int main()
{
  int n;
  float *v;
  float *resultado;

  printf("\n Digite o numero de elementos do vetor: \n");
  scanf("%d", &n);
  v = alocaVetor(n);
  printf("\n Digite: \n");
  leVetor(v, n);
  resultado = comparaVetor(v, n);

  free(v);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: É obrigatório utilizar ponteiros nesse exercício?

Comment: Dê uma estudada em escopo de variáveis. Uma variável declarada em uma função tem o escopo restrito a esta função. No caso de `alocaVetor` o melhor é passar o ponteiro para float como parâmetro da função.
Não entendi o motivo do `return v;` em `comparaVetor`.

Answer (score 1):

- Evite retornar `void`. Em geral é um desperdício, muitas vezes um erro.
- O `printf()` de um `float` não usa `&` e esse é um erro.
- Faltou acompanhar os índices do maior e menor valor. E esse é um outro erro.
- Faltou explicar melhor o que está imprimindo em cada caso. Sequer pulou de linha ou deixou um espaço ao imprimir, estivessem corretos os `printf()`.
- declare variáveis de controle do loop no próprio `for`. Nunca deixe uma variável `i` solta no meio do programa. É uma bomba relógio. Desde o final dos '80 não se usa mais isso. E antes disso se usava porque não tinha a opção de declarar no for. O comitê ISO levou anos para finalmente incluir isso na linguagem.  Mas faz tempo ;) que incluiu. Use. Desde '17  por exemplo, em C++, se pode declarar variáveis dentro da cláusula do `if()` e do `switch()` além do `for()`, tudo no sentido de diminuir o escopo (tempo de vida) das variáveis.
- Prompts na mesma linha da questão são mais agradáveis de ler. Sugiro mudar
- `main()` deve ser a primeira função de seu programa. Não a última. Vai gostar disso quando seus programas ficarem maiores ou quando for ler um programa que outro escreveu

#### essa é a saída do programa abaixo

```
Digite o numero de elementos do vetor: 4

Digite: 
Elemento 1 de 4: -12.34
Elemento 2 de 4: 2
Elemento 3 de 4: -3
Elemento 4 de 4: 55
        menor valor:   -12.34 em v[0]
        maior valor:    55.00 em v[3]
```

#### o programa de teste. Compare com o original

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


float*      alocaVetor(unsigned);
void        comparaVetor(float*, unsigned);
void        leVetor(float*, unsigned);

int main(void)
{
  unsigned n;
  float *v;
  float *resultado;

  printf("\nDigite o numero de elementos do vetor: ");
  scanf("%d", &n);
  v = alocaVetor(n);
  printf("\nDigite: \n");
  leVetor(v, n);
  comparaVetor(v, n);
  free(v);
  return 0;
}


float*      alocaVetor(unsigned n)
{
  return (float*) malloc (n * sizeof(float));
}


void        comparaVetor(float *v, unsigned n)
{
  float maior_valor = v[0];
  float menor_valor = v[0];
  int indice_do_maior = 0;
  int indice_do_menor = 0;

  for (unsigned i = 0; i < n; ++i)
  {
    if (v[i] > maior_valor)
    {
      maior_valor = v[i];
      indice_do_maior = i;
    }
    else
    {
        if (v[i] < menor_valor)
        {
            menor_valor = v[i];
            indice_do_menor = i;
        }
    };  // if()
  }
  printf("\
  \tmenor valor: %8.2f em v[%d]\n\
  \tmaior valor: %8.2f em v[%d]\n",
    menor_valor, indice_do_menor,
    maior_valor, indice_do_maior );
  return;
}


void        leVetor(float *v, unsigned n)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
  {
    printf("Elemento %d de %d: ", 1+i, n);
    scanf("%f", &v[i]);
  }
  return;
}


/*
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/481773/aloca%c3%a7%c3%a3o-din%c3%a2mica-e-uso-de-ponteiros-em-c
*/
```

Comment: **muito obrigado pela explicação e dedicação em ajudar-me**